# Taxonomy Terms No Longer Display on Terms Page after editing

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have encountered a strange issue on a site I am working on that has been active for a few years. (Drupal core 7.54) If I edit or add a new Taxonomy term, then the Taxonomy term will no longer show up on the Taxonomy term overview page (i.e. /admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary]. The term will also not show up as an option to select on a node with a corresponding term reference field.

However, if I make a view and set it to display all terms of a certain vocabulary, all the terms will show up normally. If I use Taxonomy manager module, I can successfully create the terms by adding new terms in bulk, but as soon as I edit their fields, they will disappear. I have searched far and wide, but have not encountered an similar problem and solution. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the website as user 1, the superadmin ?
Do you have any content access related modules installed.
Which widgets do you use in your Content types ?

If you have the devel module enabled, could you navigate to term/1/devel and term/2/devel where term 1 is still working item and term 2 is not working. you might spot some property that is different..

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, I was using the superuser account and I did have some content access modules, but determined them not to be an issue. Using devel, I could not determine any differences between the terms. I ended up enabling Administrative Views and all the taxonomy showed up. Then on my node's corresponding term reference field, I used hook_form_alter to insert the entire taxonomy into the drop down. It did not solve the root of the problem, but did fix the specific issue.